# Search should be triggered without an enter or search button with a delay of 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

So, I was asked to make a ReactJS page where the user should be able to able to search Movies ,series etc. from `https://omdbapi.com` and one of the conditions was that `Search should be triggered without an enter or search button with a delay of 2 seconds.` Couldn't find a direct question , thought I should post it for an easier search for others.

Answer (score 0):

So , the code is simple:

```js
var timeout
this.fetchingData = (url) => {
  timeout = setTimeout(
    () => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            return console.error('Not working')
          };
          return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            Search: data.Search,
            response: data.response,
            totalResults: data.totalResults
          })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          alert(error)
        })
    }, timeToDelay);
};

this.myStopFunction = () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

}

handlePageChange = (event) => {
  if (this.state.movieName === '') {
    console.error("ENTER MOVIE NAME FIRST")
  } else {
    this.myStopFunction()
    this.handleChange(event)
  }
}
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.myStopFunction()
  const {
    value,
    name
  } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  }, () => value ? this.myFunction(this.state, this.url, this.fetchingData) : null);
};
```

inside `return()`

```
<FormInput
  name='page'
  type='number'
  handleChange={this.handlePageChange}
  value={this.state.page}
  label='page number'
  required
/>
```

Comment: I formatted the code. Seems a stray } is before handlePageChange